# Unable to get deleted/added same files list from GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Problem Statement:

tried to get deleted/added files list in Git by running below command

1. first we deleted one file ( Commit ID: 9d0XXXX)
2. again added same file (Commit ID: 6e0XXXX)
3. modified other files ( Commit ID: 7d9XXXX)
4. trying to get same data , but the output showing empty:

---

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only 9d0XXXX 7d9XXXX
```

Output: empty.

Or

```
git diff --diff-filter=DAR  9d0XXXX 7d9XXXX
```

OUTPUT: empty.

What should I run to get this list?

---

Edit (from comment below): created Repo in GITHUB, URL : https://github.com/vikramdevops123/insert-delete

- added couple of files and deleted the same.
- trying to get the list of added and deleted file list

Scenario: I have deleted and added the same file, But i am not getting that output. `git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only 9e627f fbe54a9` or `git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only 9e627f fbe54a9`

Comment: To be clear, does commit `9d0XXXX` *lack* the file, and commit `7d9XXXX` *have* the file? Or is commit `9d0XXXX` one that *does* have the file, from before the deletion?

Comment: Step1 :deleted the file  -- 9d0XXXX 
, Step2 : Added same file(deleted file) -- 6e0XXXX 
, Step3: modified new file -- 7d9XXXX    
### i am trying to get the deleted and modified files list , but the output coming "empty"

Comment: Make a new, empty repository. Put some files in it (just dummy files). Commit a deletion, commit a restoration, commit a modification. Try the diff. Cut and paste the *entire* (text) session as a reproducer. Someone will be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: created Repo in GITHUB , URL :   https://github.com/vikramdevops123/insert-delete      , added couple of files and deleted the same. trying to get the list of added and deleted file list, 
Scenario: I have deleted and added the same file, But i am not getting that output.  

git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only 9e627f fbe54a9  or 

git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only 9e627f fbe54a9

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have your test repo on GitHub, I was able to clone it.

Here is the output from `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`:

```
+ * fbe54a9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) adding deleted file
  * aaf2163 deleting D file
  * 32c853b deleting file
  * 836a3f2 adding test file
+ * 9e627fd adding test file
  * 4a06e68 adding test file
  * 4844174 adding test file
  * 41cd5e7 deleting testc file
  * 6a92b1a adding 3rd file
  * 83fe860 adding testB file
  * 145f2ad added 1st file
```

I marked (with a plus sign `+`) the two commit hash IDs you specified in your sample `git diff-tree -r` and `git diff --diff-filter=D` commands, so that we can view and/or investigate those commits in particular.

You have selected commit `9e627fd adding test file` for the left side of your diff, and commit `fbe54a9 adding deleted file` for the right side of your commit.  Let's see what files are actually in each of these two commits:

```
$ git ls-tree -r 9e627fd
100644 blob 9d8a4e73e4f8897352d20eda060a812dab709fc9    file-A.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testB.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testD.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testE.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testc.txt
$ git ls-tree -r fbe54a9
100644 blob 9d8a4e73e4f8897352d20eda060a812dab709fc9    file-A.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testB.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testD.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testE.txt
100644 blob 5e92c1b25f72158c2378b31d29bc443ee327af81    testF.txt
```

These commits do have somewhat different file *names*.  Note that all four `test?.txt` files have the same file *content* (same blob hash ID).  For `git diff-tree`, this will not be that important:

```
$ git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only 9e627f fbe54a9
testF.txt
testc.txt
```

This looks promising.  Let's use `--name-status` instead of `--name-only` to get the *status* of each of these files:

```
$ git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-status 9e627f fbe54a9
A       testF.txt
D       testc.txt
```

So `git diff-tree` seems to be working just fine here.

Now let's take a look at `git diff`—but before we add `--diff-filter=D`, let's run it with no `--diff-filter` at all, and again with `--name-status` so that we can see what `git diff` says about the comparison of these two specific commits:

```
$ git diff --name-status 9e627f fbe54a9
R100    testc.txt       testF.txt
```

And here we have the explanation for why `--diff-filter=D` prints nothing: according to *this* diff, there is no deleted file!  There is, however, a *renamed* file, whose name was `testc.txt` in the left-side commit and `testF.txt` in the right-side commit.  The `R100` indicates that the content of the old `testc.txt` is a 100% match to the content of the new `testF.txt`.

If we don't want Git detecting renames, we must tell it not to detect renames.  (This configuration is the default in Git versions predating 2.9, but not in 2.9 and later.)  Hence, if our Git version is 2.9 or later, or if we have configured `diff.renames` to `true` or otherwise enabled it, we need to change the command line command a bit:

```
$ git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only 9e627f fbe54a9
$ git -c diff.renames=false diff --diff-filter=D --name-only 9e627f fbe54a9
testc.txt
```

With the default `diff.renames=true` setting, `git diff` uses rename detection to declare that what was called `testc.txt` was renamed to a file named `testF.txt`, as we saw in the unfiltered, `--name-status` output.  So filtering to show only `D` status files fails.  But with `-c diff.renames=false`, `git diff` does not attempt rename detection, and behaves the way `git diff-tree -r` did: it shows that file `testc.txt` is deleted.  Meanwhile, the `--diff-filter=D` tells Git not to tell us about the newly-added `testF.txt`.

#### Porcelain vs plumbing

The `git diff-tree` command falls into a category of commands that Git calls *plumbing*, while `git diff` falls into a category that Git calls *porcelain*.  The primary distinction here is in how they're intended to be used: plumbing commands are meant to behave in a simple and predictable manner and have output suitable for use by other commands.  Porcelain commands are meant to behave in a manner most useful to each user, so their output may be colored, and—this is the key to this particular problem—**may depend on user configuration**.  In this case, the user configuration item is the setting of `diff.renames`.  The `git diff-tree` command does not use `diff.renames`, but the `git diff` command does, so its output changes based on your particular configuration (and in this case, Git vintage).

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks for the information!!

deleted two files i.e. testc(ID: 32c853b) and testD(ID:aaf2163e) files and 
added testD file again(Commit ID: fbe54a9)
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-status 9e627f fbe54a9

Expected OUTPUT:

A       testF.txt
D       testc.txt
TestD.txt

Current Output:  -- Missing TestD .txt file information.
A       testF.txt
D       testc.txt
```

Comment: In the `--name-status` output, why would you expect `TestD.txt` to show up without a status code? Note that the content of commit `32c853b` is entirely irrelevant; you are comparing commits `9e627f` and `fbe54a9`.

Comment: Remember, *every commit is a snapshot*. It is not a set of changes! It just holds a snapshot of *all* of the files. To find changes, you must pick *two* commits, extract both of them, and then compare.